# React native show ICON and big image in push notifications

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

[image]Please tell me, in push notifications how to show small icon right side and big image, when notification expand big image will display in react native.
I am using push notifications with firebase.

how to show notification like in images

Comment: take a look at onesignal